# Одномерный массив в vb6

Tags: массивы, visual-basic, vb6

**Задача**

Дан массив целых чисел A = (ai), где i =(1,2,3,...,n). Напечатать числа, образующие возрастающую последовательность.
Например: если А={2,3,4,0,-1,2,-2,0,5}, результат 2,3,4 и -1,2.
Числа вводятся в отдельный текстовый блок, эту часть я сделал, а вот, как решить непосредственно задачу - понятия не имею.

Код:

```
Dim n, nw, min, i As Integer
Dim nws As String
Dim Msi() As Integer
Private Sub Command1_Click()

If Text2.Text <> "" Then
n = n + 1
nws = Text2.Text
Text2.Text = ""
nw = CInt(nws)
nws = CStr(nw)
If n = 1 Then Text1.Text = nws Else Text1.Text = Text1.Text + ", " + nws
ReDim Preserve Msi(n - 1)
Msi(n - 1) = nw
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_click()
For i = 1 To n
If Msi(n) < Msi(n - 1) Then
Text3.Text = Text3.Text + ", " + Msi(n) + "," + Msi(n - 1)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: А куда делись -1,2,5; -1,0,5; -2,0,5 и другие? Бейсик знаю, задачу не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Visual-Basic не знаю. Подскажу алгоритм:

```
{Индексация массива идет с 0; n - длина массива; }
Вывод(A[0])
Для i от 1 до n:
    Если A[i-1] >= A[i] то
        Вывод("Новая возрастающая последовательность: " + A[i] + ", ");
    Иначе
        Вывод(A[i] + ", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализация на **VBA**

```
Sub Sequences()
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Sequence() As Variant
    Dim CurrentIndex As Integer

    Arr = Array(2, 3, 4, 0, -1, 2, -2, 0, 5, 3)

    ReDim Sequence(0)
    Sequence(0) = Arr(0)
    CurrentIndex = 0
    For I = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        If Sequence(CurrentIndex) > Arr(I) Then
            MsgBox (Join(Sequence, ", "))
            ReDim Sequence(0)
            Sequence(0) = Arr(I)
            CurrentIndex = 0
        Else
            CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex + 1
            ReDim Preserve Sequence(CurrentIndex)
            Sequence(CurrentIndex) = Arr(I)
        End If
    Next
    If UBound(Sequence) = 0 Then
        MsgBox (Join(Sequence, ", "))
    End If
End Sub
```

Вывод: (2, 3, 4) _ (0) _ (-1, 2) _ (-2, 0, 5) _ (3)